App suspension in google play store without a specific reason
I got an email from Google Store, that my first version app is suspended.
This is the very first submission of the app that they had reviewed and rejected.
The mail I got is very vague and I have no idea what to do to fix the problem:

App Status: Suspended
Your app has been suspended and removed due to the policy issue(s)
listed below.
Issue found: Violation of Enforcement Process policy
Your app contains content that doesn't comply with the Developer
Program policies.
Issue details
We found an issue in the following area(s):
In-app experience: ""

To bring your app into compliance, follow these steps:
Review the Enforcement Process, Developer Program Policies and Developer Distribution Agreement for more details.
If your developer account is in good standing, you can submit an updated, policy compliant app using a new package name and a new app

name.
About the Enforcement Process policy We don’t allow apps with repeated
violations of the Developer Program Policies. Suspension can occur as
the result of egregious or multiple policy violations, as well as
repeated app rejections or removals.
Action required: Publish a new compliant version of your app
Here's what to do to help get your app on Google Play:
Make sure to read the applicable policies or requirements listed below:
    Enforcement Process policy
Make appropriate changes to your app (if possible), and be sure to address the issue described above. You may also want to check your

app's store listing for compliance, if applicable.
Double check that your app is compliant with all other Developer Program Policies.
If you made changes to your app bundle, store listing, or APK, please sign in to your Play Console and submit the update(s).

Here is a screenshot as well:


Does that mean the app crashed when it was run in their testing system?

@PresidentJamesK.Polk I don't think so, there is nothing in the email about that.

I’m voting to close this question because questions about app store policies are off topic here.  If you find a specific thing that needs code changes to fix, we can help on that.  But we have no way of knowing why google banned you.

Same thing has happened to me. App works fine, got rejected once for this reason with a screenshot of a screen that worked fine apart from a couple of fields were blank. Rebuilt hiding those fields and resubmitted and got this exact message. No proper feedback or information, no chance to have a dialogue with the review team like with Apple. Anyone got ideas on why Google has started doing this? Apple used to be the hard one. And to the previous commenter, issues with getting stuff through the review process are very on-topic for most app devs!
